# Rails 2 to 3 and deprecated gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-2

I am planning on initiating an upgrade from Rails 2 to Rails 3 for a rather *big* app. Problem is the project is relying on some old gems that are no longer supported by Rails 3.

What choices do I have, knowing that deactivating the dependant functionalities is not an option ? Are there any solutions besides looking for alternate gems ?

Comment: Ouch. Prepare for war. You could patch the gems, but aside from that, yes, you'll have to find alternative gems, remove the functionality, or build it straight into the app.

Comment: What are the unsupported gems?

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto I cannot provide you with the whole list as of now, but amongst examples are *nokogiri* gem, *juggernaut*, and an obscure *papeclip-aws* (the latter is not mispelled, and is pretty obscure).

Comment: nokogiri is still maintained so I doubt it doesn't support Rails 3, plus it's just a Ruby gem, nothing specific to Rails. Same thing apparently applies to Juggernaut, but can't be sure : https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut_plugin/issues/2. Concerning the `papeclip-aws`, you'd have to migrate to use the standard paperclip way of talking to AWS

Answer (score 0):

the biggest problems when upgrading an app to rails 3 are usually not with the update of the gems...

you can have a look at http://www.railsplugins.org/ to find out if the gems you are using are compatible. i don't know if the page is up to date, rails 3 has been around for a while and rails 4 is in the making.

these are the steps to a sane upgrade path:

- update your app to the latest 2.x.x version
- update all the gems to the latest compatible version
- create a rails3 branch (update will take a long time)
- fix all the incompatibilites in your app-code
- update/replace/patch all the gems that are not working with rails 3